# QueryBook: How to start a new environment?

Tags: sql, ide, pinterest

I've just made QueryBook, the Pinterest Query IDE. I've played around with the demo environment and now I want to see if I can connect up one of our own environments to play with purpose. I can't for the life of me figure out how to create a new environment. Any ideas? "/" defaults back to the demo environment and any other address (it's running on localhost) 404s.

I've clicked on everything that looks clickable. I don't have enough StackOverflow rep to create the tag "querybook" for this question and it also looks like the screenshot below is having issues. It's obviously a Monday kind of Wednesday.

[image: Querybook front page]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found it. Go to Settings -> Admin Tools

[image: Settings->Admin Tools]